# Why won't my rectangle move when I press the key?

Tags: javascript, game-development

So I'm trying to make a snake game from scratch a practice for making games in javascript. I've made the square inside of my canvas, and now I'm trying to make it move. This is the code I've made for it.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id = "gameCanvas" width="700" height="600" style="border:4px solid black; background-color: yellow"></canvas>

<script type = "text/javascript">
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");


    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;

    var snake = ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,10,10);

    myMovement = function(){
        var moveUp = event.keyCode;
        if(moveUp == 39){
            snake = ctx.fillRect(this.x + 1, this.y,10,10);
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, when I press the button, nothing happens. What's wrong with my code.

Comment: Why the notepad++ tag?

Comment: It's just the only free easily usable platform I know of. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: It is not related to the question

Comment: Just wondering, how do you imagine the browser will know to call your `myMovement` function? It's probably a good idea to tell the browser you wish to handle events, which events they are and finally, for which element/s on the page. A glaring ommision seems to be `.addEventListener` - do some research on javascript event handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. You are using `this` in a place where it is going to reference the global object (`window` in this case).
2. Your `myMovement` function isn't attached to anything, meaning it isn't setup as a event listener which is needed for it to be called when a key is pressed
3. Even if your myMovement was setup it didn't have the `event` object defined as a parameter so your function would have errored out as there wouldn't have been an `event` object to access

For **1** if you are meaning to you keep track of the x,y you can place them in an object and access them from there:

```
var rect={
  x:0,
  y:0
};
//then when needing to use them access them like rect.x, rect.y
//also fillRect doesn't return anything so no need for "var snake = "
ctx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, 10, 10);
```

For **2** and **3** you can use the various key* events for your function. You can attach the function by using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Finally define an `event` parameter for your function so that you actually have an event object to use:

```
function myMovement(event) {
    var moveUp = event.keyCode;
    if(moveUp == 39){
        //++rect.x adds one and assigns the new value to rect.x
        //and again fillRect doesn't return a value so no need for "snake ="
        ctx.fillRect(++rect.x, rect.y,10,10);
    }
}
window.addEventListner("keydown",myMovement);
```

---

Demo

```js
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

var rect = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

ctx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, 10, 10);

window.onkeydown = function(event) {
  var moveUp = event.keyCode;
  if (moveUp == 39) {
    //erase last fill
    ctx.clearRect(rect.x, rect.y, 10, 10);
    ctx.fillRect(++rect.x, rect.y, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="100%" height="100%" style="border:4px solid black; background-color: yellow"></canvas>
```

Comment: Seems to just move 10 pixels every time the key is pressed, shouldn't it continuously move till direction is changed?

Comment: Also is it just me or are all the variables named moveUp when they move right?

Comment: @Lorddirt in snake it should, if conforming to the original game. But that is something OP or other users to deal with as it wasn't actually part of the original problem, which was just getting it to move at all. As for the variable names yes they are mislabeled

Comment: To be honest, I don't fully understand why this is necessary most of the time. I just know that taking it out will mess things up often times.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I don't really know what you mean when your say myFunction isn't attached to anything. I didn't think it had to be.

Comment: @KhadijahMuhammad attached means setup as an event listener. Your function needs to be called in order for it to run. In your original code nothing was calling your function. So in order for it to be called on an event like a key press you have to set it up as an event listener

Answer (score 0):

problem findings:

```
  myMovement = function(){
        var moveUp = event.keyCode;
        if(moveUp == 39){
            snake = ctx.fillRect(this.x + 1, this.y,10,10);
        }
    }
```

when ***myMovement*** will fire it does not know the code, and

```
//x value just add 1 with previous but not increment gradually, so it should be this.x += 1    
ctx.fillRect(this.x + 1, this.y,10,10);
```

Solution:

```
  window.onkeyup = function(e) {
   var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

   if (key == 39) {
    snake = ctx.fillRect(this.x += 1, this.y,10,10);
   }
}
```

you can see [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/DHTML_javascript/0596004672_jvdhtmlckbk-app-b.html) for the keyboard keys value

> The onkeyup event occurs when the user releases a key (on the
>   keyboard).

Actually there are 3 different options to fire key event

***onkeydown***

***onkeypress***

***onkeyup***

Comment: why window.onkeyup?

Comment: The onkeyup event occurs when the user releases a key (on the keyboard).

Comment: What I mean is, why is window attached to onkeyup instead of the object

Comment: and shouldn't it be onkeydown

Comment: Actually there are 3 different options to fire key event onkeydown, onkeypress, onkeyup. so you can use any one depending on your needs. you can see my post I mentioned